# Android Emulator wont start ("exit code -1073741511 (0xC0000139)")

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

i cant get the Android emulator to start. Error:

```
Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741511 (0xC0000139)
```

Ive read a lot about this error and tried everything i could find, so thats what i know (and have checked):

- Intel HAXM is installed
- Intel VT is enabled (and supported by my CPU)
- Hyper-V is disabled
- Disk space is not a problem (>450gb free)
- RAM is not a problem (i allocated 4gb)
- ive tried various images, no success
- reinstalled Android Studio (and AVD)

Some additional information:

- Android Emulator version: 7.3.2
- Android Studio version: 3.2.1
- OS: Windows 10

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I had a similar problem in the past. Do you have docker installed in your machine? If yes, It could be your problem and you can use a docker container to run the Android Emulator. Take a look at thyrlian/android-sdk

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i havent Docker (yet) installed, but i will have a look in to it.